# GitHub continuous integration to validate a CSV/TSV file

Tags: gratis, csv, github, validation

I have a GitHub project which consists mostly of a TSV file.

People often send pull requests, and each time most of the work is to simply check that it is valid TSV. People often break TSV by forgetting a tab or using spaces inside or lacking a column, or using a wrong encoding.

That's where continuous integration would really help, by checking these technical things and letting me focus on the actual content changes brought by the pull request.

On each pull request I see:

[image: GitHub continuous integration]

But when I click the link and search for "TSV" or "CSV", nothing shows up.

Is there an easily configurable GitHub continuous integration to check a TSV or CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

As a GitHub-round developer, IMO, "checking CSV/TSV" is a task too specific to make a dedicated app useful, and that's why there isn't a ready-for-use one.

I would instead propose that you just use Travis CI or CircleCI, and write a CI config that runs some other command-line validator tool (you can even write one yourself with regular expressions), and Travis or Circle will show a status to every *pushed* commit.